# SSL: Can I use the same SSL Certificate both for Web and Mail services on the same server?

Tags: apache, ssl, smtp

My application performs ajax calls to a remote server that monitors incoming emails for multiple recipients and retrieves them if there are new ones. For security measure, I need to use HTTPS for the calls and also make the email retrieval secure.

My questions, as the title states, can I use the same SSL Certificate both for Web and Mail services on the same server having the same domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The clients receiving the certificate will accept it, since the certificate they receive will match the domain name they are contacting.

If it is recommended?Well it would be better to deploy different certificate per interface, if it is possible.

Comment: I'm compelled at the moment to buy a single certificate in order to minimize overhead as much as possible. Does this solution work for all SSL certificates issued by all providers across all servers?

Comment: If the certificate issued has proper X509v3 extensions so that there is no interoperability issues, and the certificate is issued under the a domain that matches the domain name that the clients try to reach, then there should not be any issues

Answer (score 1):

One my mail servers, I use the same VeriSign issued x509 certificate/private key for apache, postfix, and cyrus (for imaps/pop3s) and it works fine.

It's possible that some issued certs have fields that a particular mail server won't like, but unless it's something non-standard, I can't see the popular MTA's (like sendmail, postfix, qmail, etc.) choking on it.

You also have to make sure to convert your cert/key to the format the service expects it in. Apache, postfix, cyrus all work with PEM x509 and RSA private key.

Comment: Do you have an idea if this works with Comodo issued certificates?